# How to determine correct changepoints from Posterior Probabilities (bcp R package)?

Tags: r, time-series, bayesian, change-point

I am using the bcp package in R to determine change points in a time series. The output that this package gives is a distribution of posterior probabilities.

As far as I can understand, the peak points in this distribution must be change points, but this way I am getting a lot of false positives as in the original data, not all of the peak points are coming out to be change points.

There must be a threshold value that I can consider to declare a peak as a change point. How can I determine that? Is there any other way to find the change points?

Comment: The discussion here is relevant to the posterior probability analysis for changepoint identification: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/470473/minimum-posterior-probability-for-bayesian-changepoint-analysis-in-r/571246#571246

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially the difference between the output from a frequentist and Bayesian procedure.  To get frequentist type output i.e. point estimates one typically uses the Bayesian Maximum a posteriori (MAP) estimation.  This essentially chooses a threshold and returns the modes above that threshold.  You are then back to the frequentist world of "what threshold is appropriate?" which is the same as asking "how long is a piece of string?".

Typically people use thresholds based on the Bayes Factor, for example:

http://www.lancs.ac.uk/~killick/Pub/EckleyFearnheadKillick2010.pdf

shows how this choice can be made and:

http://eprints.lancs.ac.uk/8189/1/PScpt2.pdf

provides a histogram of number of changes against posterior probability too indicating that the mode of that histogram should be chosen.