# Minimum posterior probability for Bayesian changepoint analysis in R

Tags: r, bayesian, change-point

I have the following data set:

Here is the sample data for this:

```
structure(list(V1 = c(7L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 4L)), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-40L))
```

I am using the **bcp** package in R to detect change points.

```
bcp_x <- bcp(dat$count, return.mcmc = TRUE)
plot(bcp_x)
```

[image: output]

**Questions:**

According to this tutorial,

https://www.marinedatascience.co/blog/2019/09/28/comparison-of-change-point-detection-methods/

at least 70% of the Posterior probability should be exceeded to be considered as a significant changepoint. In my data set I can see two peaks around 10 and 19, but probabilities are 0.4 and 0.6 respectively. How true is this minimum 70% for the Bayesian changepoint threshold?

Any thoughts on this? Maybe the Bayesian method is not appropriate for this data set? How can I determine the minimum probability to consider the peaks as significant?

I'll appreciate any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 6):

In case it may be useful for those who still check this old question, here are some additional thoughts, especially to your second question: **Is there an accepted method or r-package that is used for determining the optimal number of changepoints in a given a time series?** First, a similar question was asked here at [How to determine correct changepoints from Posterior Probabilities (bcp R package)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223779/how-to-determine-correct-changepoints-from-posterior-probabilities-bcp-r-packag).

As some background information, in Bayesian inference, the *number of changepoints* (`ncp`) is not an unknown constant but a random variable by itself, so the Bayesian result will give a posterior distribution of ncp. There is no concept like optimal number of changepoints unless we further introduce a utility function to optimize. Instead, a reasonable thing to do is to just get some statistics (e.g.,  mean, mode, median, and percentiles) from the distribution of ncp, just as typically done for any probability distributions.  As I recall, `bcp` doesn't dump the distribution of ncp (I may be wrong). A package I developed called `Rbeast` (available at https://github.com/zhaokg/Rbeast) dumps the distribution of ncp, as illustrated below for your data.

```
Y = c(7L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 4L)

library(Rbeast)

# Rbeast does time series decompositon and changepoint detection at the same time.
# Y doesn't have any periodic/seasonal variation, so set season='none'
# By default, beast fits a linear sloped model (y=ax+b) for each segment

o = beast(Y, season='none')

# your bcp code fits a constant or flat line to each segment; this can be done
# in Rbeast by setting the min and max order of the polynomial segment to c(0,0).

o = beast(Y, season='none', torder.minmax=c(0,0))

print(o)
plot(o)
```

Shown below are the posterior distribution of ncp and a summary of several common statistics derived from it. In `Rbeast`, I used the median (ncp_median) as the default 'optimal` number of changepoints when plotting in the function plot().

```
#####################################################################
#                      Trend  Changepoints                          #
#####################################################################
.-------------------------------------------------------------------.
| Ascii plot of probability distribution for number of chgpts (ncp) |
.-------------------------------------------------------------------.
|Pr(ncp = 0 )=0.035|*****                                           |
|Pr(ncp = 1 )=0.174|**********************                          |
|Pr(ncp = 2 )=0.378|*********************************************** |
|Pr(ncp = 3 )=0.276|***********************************             |
|Pr(ncp = 4 )=0.107|**************                                  |
|Pr(ncp = 5 )=0.026|****                                            |
|Pr(ncp = 6 )=0.004|*                                               |
|Pr(ncp = 7 )=0.000|*                                               |
|Pr(ncp = 8 )=0.000|*                                               |
|Pr(ncp = 9 )=0.000|*                                               |
.-------------------------------------------------------------------.
|    Summary for number of Trend ChangePoints (tcp)                 |
.-------------------------------------------------------------------.
|ncp_max    = 9    | MaxTrendKnotNum: A parameter you set           |
|ncp_mode   = 2    | Pr(ncp= 2)=0.38: There is a 37.8% probability  |
|                  | that the trend component has  2 changepoint(s).|
|ncp_mean   = 2.34 | Sum{ncp*Pr(ncp)} for ncp = 0,...,9             |
|ncp_pct10  = 1.00 | 10% percentile for number of changepoints      |
|ncp_median = 2.00 | 50% percentile: Median number of changepoints  |
|ncp_pct90  = 4.00 | 90% percentile for number of changepoints      |
.-------------------------------------------------------------------.
| List of probable trend changepoints ranked by probability of      |
| occurrence: Please combine the ncp reported above to determine    |
| which changepoints below are  practically meaningful              |
'-------------------------------------------------------------------'
|tcp#              |time (cp)                  |prob(cpPr)          |
|------------------|---------------------------|--------------------|
|1                 |18.000000                  |0.72929             |
|2                 |11.000000                  |0.53813             |
|3                 |23.000000                  |0.17671             |
|4                 |31.000000                  |0.13967             |
|5                 |34.000000                  |0.13675             |
|6                 |6.000000                   |0.10292             |
.-------------------------------------------------------------------.
```

#### Additional comments on your original question:

I just want to re-iterate the excellent points made by Thomas Lumley. There is no set standard/threshold for determining the presence/absence of changepoints. In the application fields I am familiar with, the choice of the thresholds is problem-specific and, in many cases, inspired by domain expert knowledge.

Regardless, one important clarification is:  A higher peak indicates a higher chance of being a changepoint only at that particular SINGLE point in time (suppose your data is a time series) and does not necessarily mean a higher chance of observing a changepoint AROUND that time. For example, a window of posterior changepoint occurrence probability values c(0,0,0.5,0,0) (i.e., the peak prob is 0.5 and the summed prob is 0.5) is less likely to be a changepoint compared to another window c(0.1,0.2,0.21,0.2,0.1) (i.e., the peak prob is 0.21 but the summed prob is 0.71). That is, it is not reliable to check only the peak value; rather, a more reasonable metric is to look around the neighbors around the peak and use the summed prob.

Answer (score 5):

That's not what the tutorial says. It says, about one example where there's an obvious changepoint

> The lower posterior probability plot shows that at one location (looks
>   like #28) the probability of a change is very high. We can get the
>   exact locations where probabilities are high (e.g. > 70%) with this
>   code:

That's not a criterion for saying there is a changepoint; it's code for finding where the changepoint is when you know it has high probability.

Typically you'd want to use a much lower threshold than 70%. Even a threshold of 50% requires that it's more likely than not that there's threshold at precisely this point. If the location of the threshold is uncertain by one or two time units it will be hard to meet a 50% probability threshold for any one time point.

In your example I would say you have evidence for two changepoints.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think this line: 'The highest posterior probabilities for a change are found at location 10, 26 and 46. But only at #26 is the probability higher then 70%, which is considered the minimum to indicate a significant change.' The part with multiple changepoint.  I have another question. Is there an accepted method or r-package that is used for determining the optimal number of changepoints in a given a time series?